# Intersecting rectangles in space

Tags: c++, data-structures, spatial

I need to intersect 1 million spatial polygons (specified using their Minimum Bounding Rectangles) with 4 completely disjoint MBR's (MBR1,MBR2,MBR3,MBR4) in space. MBR1, MBR2, MBR3 and MBR4 divide the entire space into 4 disjoint parts. For doing so, I wrote the following code. However, it turns out that for 1 million points the code is running very slowly. Is there some way by which I may improve the code so that it may run a bit faster. If yes, then can someone please help with the same

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct MBR
{
    double xRight, xLeft, yBottom, yTop;
};
bool intersects(MBR spatialId,MBR mbr) 
{
    if (mbr.yBottom > spatialId.yTop || mbr.yTop < spatialId.yBottom) return false;
    if (mbr.xLeft > spatialId.xRight || mbr.xRight < spatialId.xLeft) return false;        
    return true;    
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool contains(MBR spatialId,MBR mbr) 
{
    if (mbr.yBottom > spatialId.yBottom || mbr.yTop < spatialId.yTop) return false;
    if (mbr.xLeft > spatialId.xLeft || mbr.xRight < spatialId.xRight) return false;
    return true;    
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool touches(MBR spatialId,MBR mbr) 
{
    if (    (mbr.yBottom >= spatialId.yBottom + std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() && 
            mbr.yBottom <= spatialId.yBottom - std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()) ||
            (mbr.yTop >= spatialId.yTop + std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() &&
            mbr.yTop <= spatialId.yTop - std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()))
            return true;
    if (    (mbr.xLeft >= spatialId.xLeft + std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() &&
            mbr.xLeft <= spatialId.xLeft - std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()) ||
            (mbr.xRight >= spatialId.xRight + std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() &&
            mbr.xRight <= spatialId.xRight - std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()))
            return true;    
    return false;    
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MBR MBR1,MBR2,MBR3,MBR4;
vector<unsigned> spatialIds; //contain 1 million spatial identifiers which are intersected with MBR1, MBR2, MBR3, MBR4
//MBR1, MBR2, MBR3, MBR4 are again specified using their Minimum Bounding Rectangles
vector<unsigned> result; //contains the resulting intersecting spatial ids
for(vector<MBR>::iterator itSpatialId=spatialIds.begin(),lSpatialId=spatialIds.end();itSpatialId!=lSpatialId;++itSpatialId)
{
    if(intersects((*itSpatialId),MBR1)||contains((*itSpatialId),MBR1)||touches((*itSpatialId),MBR1))
    {
        result.push_back((*itSpatialId));
    }

    if(intersects((*itSpatialId),MBR2)||contains((*itSpatialId),MBR2)||touches((*itSpatialId),MBR2))
    {
        result.push_back((*itSpatialId));
    }                    

    if(intersects((*itSpatialId),MBR3)||contains((*itSpatialId),MBR3)||touches((*itSpatialId),MBR3))
    {
        result.push_back((*itSpatialId));
    }   

    if(intersects((*itSpatialId),MBR4)||contains((*itSpatialId),MBR4)||touches((*itSpatialId),MBR4))
    {
        result.push_back((*itSpatialId));
    }   
}
```

Comment: This question is too broad. There are dozens of ways to improve the time.  If your 1 million MBRs are relatively fixed (I'm assume asteroids or some such), you can sort their locations and use Binary Space Partitioning and trivially reject large numbers of possible collisions.  StackOverflow is for questions that have ONE exact, specific, answer.  As is, no answer can be marked as "correct".

Comment: @StevenHansen Thank you very much for your help. How can I sort the locations and apply Binary search. I am a novice in the spatial domain. If possible, I'll be thankful if you can help with this a little. I tried a lot on my own but I am unable to figure out

Comment: There are *tons* of articles and tutorials all over the internet. Try google for "Binary Space Partitioning tutorial".  If you get stuck at a specific point in your implementation, *that* would be where posts on StackOverflow become useful; though I would consider http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ since BSP is more of a game programming topic.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify the intersection test.

First, I don't think the `epsilon` is necessary when comparing two values, the comparison operator does not introduce any numerical error.

Second, you only need to check the following:

```
bool intersectsContainsOrTouches(MBR spatialId,MBR mbr) 
{
    return (mbr.yBottom <= spatialId.yTop && mbr.yTop >= patialId.yBottom) &&     
        (mbr.xLeft <= spatialId.xRight && mbr.xRight >= spatialId.xLeft);
}
```

Normally, you would use BSP or a multidimensional index to perform a spatial 'JOIN' operation. But since you have only 4 rectangles to join with, it should be faster to simply iterate through all 1M rectangles and compare each one with the 4 MBRs. 
I'm not sure that multi-dimensional indexes or binary space partitioning would help here.

Btw, how long does it take? It should clearly be less than a minute, is that a problem?

**EDIT**

If you have to do this repeatedly, I would put the data into a spatial index, then you can perform four window queries on the index for each of your MBRs.
There are also dedicated algorithms, such as [TOUCH](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/186338?ln=en).
If you are using Java, have a look at my [PH-Tree](http://www.phtree.org) (which is also good when individual rectangles are added/removed or moved. For other languages, check R-Tree (R+tree, X-Tree, ..), kd-trees or quadtrees.

For C++, you could have a look at [ODE](http://www.ode.org). It's a 3D game physics engine that internally has several algorithms for detecting MBR overlaps (Quadtrees, SAP-Space, ...).

Comment: I need to run the tests again and again for different spatial points with MBR1, MBR2, MBR3 and MBR4. Therefore, its taking 30 minutes

Comment: Then I would really use a spatial index, see my updates above.